# Imageslider with description

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a fully working imageslider with an Adapter and indicator dots. But now I want to add descriptions for each image with a TextView. Anyone have an idea how to do this? Thank you.

EDIT: see code below

MainActivity.java:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] imageUrls = new String[]{
            "http://image1.png",
            "http://image2.png",
            "http://image3.png",
            "http://image4.png",
            "http://image5.png"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageUrls);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: u can change layout of that image slider element and add what u want. It's easy to explain when u put some codes here

Comment: Of course. I updated the post with my MainActivity and activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove image view from xml file. only keep viewpager element there.

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Then u need to create custom adapter with layout what u want. You can find steps to create custom adapter by following this https://inducesmile.com/android/understanding-android-viewpager-and-custom-pageradapter/

then u need to change  `viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);` to set object of your custom adapter

Comment: Nice to hear it. Happy coding